# Find the least duplicate items in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay so as the title says my goal is to find the least duplicate elements, given that the elements are only integers.

`ex1: array = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3]` result should be `1,2`

`ex2: array = [1,2,2,3,3,4]` result should be `1,4`

I could use the xor operator to find the elements that appear only once but since there might be only duplicates I cant.

I was thinking of first checking with XOR if the're any non-duplicate elements. If no proceed with `for`s to check for only two occurrences of the same element and so on, but that is not a good approach as its kinda slow,

any suggestions?

Comment: are the items sorted?

Comment: no, I could sort them though, but I'd like to avoid doing so, in case its not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, using `new Set()` and few `Array.prototype` functions. If you have any questions, let me know.

```js
var array1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    array2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];

function sort(arr) {
  var filtered = [...new Set(arr)],
      solution = [],
      res = filtered.reduce(function(s, a) {
        s.push(arr.filter(c => c == a).length);
        return s;
      }, []);

  var minDupe = Math.min.apply([], res);
  res.forEach((v, i) => v == minDupe ? solution.push(filtered[i]) : null)
  console.log(solution)
}

sort(array1);
sort(array2);
```

Using `Array#forEach` instead of `Array#reduce`.

```js
var array1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    array2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];

function sort(arr) {
  var filtered = [...new Set(arr)],
      solution = [],
      res = [];
      filtered.forEach(v => res.push(arr.filter(c => c == v).length));
      
  var minDupe = Math.min.apply([], res);
  res.forEach((v, i) => v == minDupe ? solution.push(filtered[i]) : null)
  console.log(solution)
}

sort(array1);
sort(array2);
```

Comment: Indeed that is a valid solution to my problem but I think its a bit slower compared to others (I may be wrong), thank you though.

Comment: @nonerth Don't worry it's not that slow as you would think ;d

Comment: I dont really get the `res = filtered.reduce..`, couldnt it be done with a for each again, excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You are as your name suggests huh :p, Its correct as it is, but if you could I think it would make it easier to read and understand, thanks

Comment: Okee, I think I am gonna accept this solution, if you dont mind I am gonna wait a bit before doing so, as to wait for any corrections to other answers for future reference.

Comment: one more question, are you using the minDupe to return the smaller number first?

Comment: @nonerth `minDupe` is amount of appearances of item (or items) which appears least (the least duplicate appearances).

Comment: whats the purpose of the `...` before the iterable, I looked at MDN but it didnt explain. it 'copies' to `new Set` the array right?

Comment: It's a `spread operator`. It changes the set into an array instantly. https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Spread_operator

Comment: Thank you very much yet again!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better or faster solution, but I would suggest to create a hash (object) with the integer as keys and the counts as values. You can create this in one loop of the array. Then, loop over the object keys keeping track of the minimum value found and add the key to the result array if it satisfies the minimum duplicate value.

Example implementation:

```
const counts = input.reduce((counts, num) => {
    if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
        counts[num] = 1;
    }
    else {
        counts[num]++;
    }
    return counts;
}, {});

let minimums = [];
let minCount = null;
for (const key in counts) {
    if (!minimums.length || counts[key] < minCount) {
        minimums = [+key];
        minCount = counts[key];
    }
    else if (counts[key] === minCount) {
        minimums.push(+key);
    }
}

return minimums;
```

You can also simplify this a little bit using lodash: one operation to get the counts and another to get the minimum count and get the list of values that match that minimum count as a key:

```
import { countBy, invertBy, min, values } from "lodash";

const counts = countBy(input);
const minCount = min(values(counts));

return invertBy(counts)[minCount];
```

Comment: could you explain the second for a bit if possible

Answer (score 0):

You could count the appearance, sort by count and delete all same max count keys. Then return the original values.

Steps:

- declarate all variables, especial the hash object without any prototypes,
- use the items as key got the hash table and if not set use an object with the original value and a count property,
- increment count of actual hash,
- get all keys from the hash table,
- sort the keys in descending order of count,
- get the count of the first element and store it in `min`,
- filter all keys with `min` count,
- get the original value for all remaining keys.

```js
function getLeastDuplicateItems(array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null), keys, min;
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a] = hash[a] || { value: a, count: 0 };
        hash[a].count++;
    });
    keys = Object.keys(hash);
    keys.sort(function (a, b) { return hash[a].count - hash[b].count; });
    min = hash[keys[0]].count;
    return keys.
        filter(function (k) {
            return hash[k].count === min;
        }).
        map(function (k) {
           return hash[k].value;
        });
}

var data = [
        [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 3, 3]
    ];

console.log(data.map(getLeastDuplicateItems));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A single loop solution with a variable for `min` and an array for collected count.

```js
function getLeastDuplicateItems(array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        temp = [],
        min = 1;

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var p = (temp[hash[a]] || []).indexOf(a);
        hash[a] = (hash[a] || 0) + 1;
        temp[hash[a]] = temp[hash[a]] || [];
        temp[hash[a]].push(a);
        if (min > hash[a]) {
            min = hash[a];
        }
        if (p === -1) {
            return;
        }
        temp[hash[a] - 1].splice(p, 1);
        if (min === hash[a] - 1 && temp[hash[a] - 1].length === 0) {
            min++;
        }
    }, []);
    return temp[min];
}

var data = [
        [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 3, 3],
    ];

console.log(data.map(getLeastDuplicateItems));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Its seems a bit complicated but correct!, for future googlers (and myself :p) it'd be good if you could explain it a bit

Comment: I'm afraid that it won't work when entries are not sorted :C

Comment: the sort order of the original array does not matter, because of the hash table.

Comment: Try `[4,4,4,6,6,4,7,8,5,5,6,3,4,6,6,7,7,8,3,3]`. Proper result should be `[8,5]`.

Comment: But `7` and `3` appears three times, while `5` and `8` only two times. We are looking for numbers which appear least likely.

Comment: Yep, Kind user is correct, since they exist numbers that appear only twice the others are out of the game.